# How to create default empty dict to combine filter in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I write a role. In defaults/main.yml I have:

```
sysctl:
  net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1
  vm.swappiness: 10
```

tasks/main.yml:

```
- name: Setup sysctl.conf
  sysctl: name="{{ item.0 }}" value="{{ item.1 }}" state=present
  become: yes
  loop: "{{ sysctl_default | combine(sysctl) | dictsort }} "
```

If user doesn't define `sysctl` in vars ansible will raise an error. Default parameters must be set if user skip this settings. How to create empty dictionary if user ommit sysctl settings in his playbook? Such expression `{{ sysctl_default | combine(sysctl | default({})) | dictsort }}` doesn't working:

```
fatal: [192.168.140.96]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined"}
```

Comment: i think it makes more sense to add a `when` clause in your task, to check if the `sysctl` variable is defined and has items. by adding a default filter, what are you planning to achieve? run the `sysctl` task without a valid change to do?

Comment: I plan to add `net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1` by default, because this role is for router. So, even if user skip this setting it will be ok, the role take care of it explicitly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: "{{ sysctl_default | combine(sysctl | default({}) | dictsort }} doesn't working"

A: ... because of the missing closing parenthesis ")". Correct syntax is

```
{{ sysctl_default | combine(sysctl|default({})) | dictsort }}
```

> Q: "Again this not working: fatal: [192.168.140.96]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined"}"

A: The next problem is the undefined variable sysctl_default. For example the play

```
  vars:
    sysctl_default:
      net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1
      vm.swappiness: 10
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "name={{ item.0 }} value={{ item.1 }} state=present"
      loop: "{{ sysctl_default | combine(sysctl|default({})) | dictsort }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "name=net.inet.ip.forwarding value=1 state=present"
"msg": "name=vm.swappiness value=10 state=present"
```

Comment: Thanks for note, but again this not working: ``fatal: [192.168.140.96]: FAILED! => {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got AnsibleUndefined"}``

Comment: The next problem is the undefined variable ``sysctl_default``.

Comment: It's very strange! But your play is working well on my virtual machine, but not on OpenBSD :) Is it possible this caused by python version? On my local machine it's 3.5.2, on my OpenBSD machine it's a 3.6.8.

Comment: I don't think so. The play works fine on FreeBSD 12.0 with ``python version = 3.6.8``

Comment: Sorry, the play works well on OpenBSD too. But when I start my role I've got this fatal error. I have a mistake somewhere. I will try to find it. Thanks for your help, Vladimir!

Comment: The error was in defaults\main.yml where I defined `sysctl` not `sysctl_default`. Oh my... spent a lot of time looking for a problem. :( Sorry again, guys.